# How to solve the issue "A required library with BLAS API not found"?

Tags: terminal, compiler-errors, cygwin, lapack, blas

I am trying to install JDFTx by simply following the instructions on the page http://jdftx.org/CompilingBasic.html.

I have installed Cygwin from here (Windows, x64): https://cygwin.com/install.html . And I also believe that I have installed necessary libraries, listed here: http://jdftx.org/Dependencies.html .

Now, when I enter in the Cygwin64 terminal the command:

```
cmake ../jdftx-VERSION/jdftx
```

I am getting the following message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:690 (message):
  A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:165 (find_package)
  CMake-Modules/FindLAPACK_ATLAS.cmake:20 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:85 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/jdftx/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/jdftx/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The solution is to use this command instead, thus explicitly specifying the location of the library:

```
cmake -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a ../jdftx-1.4.1/jdftx
```

However, now I am getting the following output, containing another error message:

```
    -- Forcing static linking for Cygwin/Windows
-- Found GSL: /lib/libgsl.dll.a
-- Found FFTW3:  /lib/libfftw3_threads.dll.a /lib/libfftw3.dll.a
-- Found LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a
-- Found CBLAS: /usr/lib/libgslcblas.dll.a
-- Found MPI_C: /usr/lib/libmpi.dll.a;/usr/lib/libopen-rte.dll.a;/usr/lib/libope                                                     n-pal.dll.a;/usr/lib/libm.a;/usr/lib/w32api/libgdi32.a
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:420 (message):
  Unable to find MPI library mpi_cxx
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:610 (interrogate_mpi_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:93 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmak                                                     e:148 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA                                                     _FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:628 (find_package_handle_standard                                                     _args)
  CMakeLists.txt:93 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/jdftx/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/jdftx/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Would anyone have an idea what other option should I use in the `cmake` call?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -cd | grep lapack` ?

Comment: This is the output: 

lapack-debuginfo                        3.8.0-1

liblapack-devel                         3.8.0-1

liblapack-doc                           3.8.0-1
liblapack0                              3.8.0-1

mingw64-i686-lapack                     3.7.0-1

mingw64-x86_64-lapack                   3.7.0-1

Comment: The developer suggested to use this command: cmake -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a ../jdftx-1.4.1/jdftx   and it worked. But now I have further errors.. (see updated question)

Comment: the open mpi C++ interface was removed upstream https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/the-mpi-c-bindings-what-happened-and-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
cmake -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a -DMPI_CXX_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.dll.a ../jdftx-1.4.1/jdftx
```

Now I realize, this is not a solution for the second error...

The actual solution is to uninstall all related libraries and install previous versions (instead of the newest ones). After I have done it, everything works fine.

Comment: Strange, cmake should be able to find lapack and blas in their canonical place `/usr/lib/liblapack.dll.a` `/usr/lib/libblas.dll.a` ; check that you have also `/usr/lib/lapack` in the PATH. Please also note that `/usr/lib/libgslcblas.dll.a` is the GSL CBLAS interface so another thing from the standard CBLAS

Comment: No, the variable is not there.. What variable name should I use if I want to create a variable for /usr/lib/lapack ?

Comment: I believe the solution posted is not a solution, since i am having errors when running "make -j4" command, and then when I type "make test", all tests are failed

Comment: Should I go into System Properties's Environment Variables window to create a variable, or there is a configure file somewhere that is better to use for this purpose?

Comment: See `/etc/profile.d/lapack0.sh` for proper setting of the PATH under `bash`